# Singleton lock implementation does not lock threads as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, mutex

In my real program, I need to share the same lock over all the code, so I decided to write a `SingletonLock` to access it anywhere without passing it to multiple functions. The implementation is the following:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _singleton_instance = None
    _singleton_lock: Lock = Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        with cls._singleton_lock:
            if cls._singleton_instance is None:
                _singleton_instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return _singleton_instance


class SingletonLock(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()

    def acquire(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        print('locked')

    def release(self):
        self.lock.release()
        print('released')

    def release_if_locked(self):
        if self.lock.locked():
            self.lock.release()
```

And I have the following concept to test it :

```
import threading
import time
from threading import Lock

# import the class

def t1():
    try:
        SingletonLock().acquire()
        cntr = 10

        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cntr = cntr - 1
            print(f't1: {cntr}')
            if cntr == 0:
                SingletonLock().release()
                return
    finally:
        SingletonLock().release_if_locked()


def t2():
    try:
        SingletonLock().acquire()
        cntr = 100

        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cntr = cntr - 1
            print(f't2: {cntr}')
            if cntr == 0:
                SingletonLock().release()
                return

    finally:
        SingletonLock().release_if_locked()


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=t1).start()
    threading.Thread(target=t2).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but the output tells us it does not lock the lock, or even, locks the lock twice.

```
locked
locked
t1: 9
t2: 99
t1: 8
t2: 98
t1: 7
t2: 97
t1: 6
t2: 96
t1: 5
t2: 95
t1: 4
t2: 94
t1: 3
t2: 93
t1: 2
t2: 92
t1: 1
t2: 91
t1: 0
t2: 90
python-BaseException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/test/a.py", line 46, in t1
    SingletonLock().release()
  File "/test/a.py", line 28, in release
    self.lock.release()
RuntimeError: release unlocked lock
```

and if I use just casual global lock it works as expected. I wonder, what is the reason of such behavior? I tried to check metaclass' lock instances with `id()`, the address is the same.

Comment: "and if I use just casual global lock it works as expected" - so why didn't you just use a simple global lock? It'd be much simpler and more reliable.

Comment: Your whole `release_if_locked` thing is fundamentally unsafe, for one thing. If *any* thread has that lock locked, it'll try to unlock the lock.

Comment: Your `SingletonMeta` is broken, too, since it never sets `cls._singleton_instance`. Even if it worked, you've got a `SingletonMeta._singleton_lock` lock to protect a singleton, which itself just wraps a lock. All you need is one lock, not all this extra singleton machinery piling even more locks on top.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, while I was writing the question I realized I can just lock which I will import from a separate file, but what I do not understand is why the class does not work, because for me it looks fine